# TypeScript version different from WebStorm to local

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm, typescript1.8

I've installed NodeJS v6.x on my Ubuntu 15.10 and TypeScript version is 1.8.10. When I'm looking for `tsc` version in my WebStorm settings I found 1.6.2.

How is it possible?

Comment: WebStorm contains own built-in version of typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It use Webstorm bundled Typescript version.

You can change by go to `Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / TypeScript` and select Edit close to `Typescript version`